# How exit from a timeline in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

i have this code

```
private static int seconds = 0 ;

        public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException{
       //some code
      //then add a timer because i want to change this stage's scene after 7 seconds
       final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new EventHandler() {
            @Override public void handle(Event event) {

               seconds++
               if(seconds>=7){

                   AnotherScene mainmenu = new AnotherScene ();
                   try {
                       AnotherScene .startScene(stage);
//i have startScene methode in AnotherScene  classthat give this stage and load another fxml file
                   } catch (IOException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(startUpScene.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   }
               }
            }
             }),  
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0)));
            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.play();//start timer
//some code
stage.show();
}
```

i can change scene of my stage but i have a problem i see this timer works for my AnotherScene because i add a static int 'a' in AnotherScene and print 'a' in AnotherSceneController and see every seconds print this integer any ideas for exiting from timer ? thanks

Edit:

i change `timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);` to `timeline.setCycleCount(8);` and my problem solved but any better Ideas?

Comment: I don't have JavaFX so i cant check it but cant you extract timeline object from `Event` and then calll method `timeline.stop()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(7));
delay.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // do whatever you needed to do after the seven second pause
    }
});
delay.play();
```